# docker-compose container web applications through open vpn

Tags: networking, docker-compose, openvpn

I'm trying to run a web application in a docker container, that as part of it's bootstrap it goes to get some information from services reachable through an open vpn.
The host machine is Mac and i couldn't find any way to do so.

The web application is jetty app running in docker-compose.
I need that other containers will be able to link to the webapp.

any idea ...?

Docker version:
Client:
 Version:   17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:03:51 2017
 OS/Arch:   darwin/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: true

Comment: does the vpn configuration and connection exist on the host machine?

Comment: Yes , I'm running the exact same commands from the host machine and it the web app start properly

Comment: i dont understand what you want... your container will try to access VPN by ip lets say 10.0.0.1, the host knows there is vpn for this IP and will route the request there... so what is not working ?

Comment: how can i make the container to access vpn

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the path on your config file on your docker-compose.yaml so then you will be able to have it configure .
etc I guess something like https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/blob/master/docs/docker-compose.md

Hope that helps!

Comment: The link is broken cann you provide different link?

Comment: If you could try now!

Comment: maybe similar config to this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757424/docker-compose-scale-up-jetty-with-nginx-at-runtime)